# Number Reset as Beginning of the Month

Tags: workflow, custom-list, calculated-column

I have an ticket tracking system in a SharePoint list that runs by a Fiscal year, month, then counts for the month.  And my leadership wants to automate the number assignment.

Ex: ABC (current calendar year) - 01 (Jan) - 0001 (incident #) will read fully as ABC-01-0001.  I've got the ABC and Month figured out.  I have a 2010 workflow set up to assign those numbers upon creation.  I'm stuck on resetting the incident number (0001) at the beginning of each month. For Feb it would be ABC-02-0001.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can you use javascript ?

Comment: Yes, that is an option

Comment: Check [Auto Serial Number in SharePoint New Form](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/auto-serial-number-new-form-sharepoint/) and customize your CAML Query as you prefer

Answer (score 0):

Can you create another list which will hold the next incident # and the month?

In your workflow you would compare the current month against stored month List item

1. If its different,  Update month and reset the next incident # to 1 and set current incident number as 0.
2. If its same, Use the next incident number and update your ticket number in required format and then update next incident number to Current Next Incident Number+1.

Comment: That sounds perfect.  How would I compare the months?  Would it be a calculated column?  Or just a current date field?  Thank you for the help!

Comment: You will always have two columns in the above list along with one item.

Example item would be December - 933. 

In the workflow you would compare the current month with this item "December". If Current Month  matches December your  ticket number would be CurrentMonth(In workflow)-933 else you would update month in the item to January and reset count to 1

Please mark as answer if it helped you